# How do I replace queries in the URL when on the same path? | Without useHistory() if possible

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a page that displays products returned from my API based on the URL's search parameters. For example, '/products?search=socks' would return products with the word `socks` in the title. The search bar is located in the header. If I search for a product on the home page (a different path: '/'), it navigates to the product list page and displays the products. However, if I search for a product on the product list page (the same path: '/products'), it re-renders and removes the search parameters, leading to no products being displayed. I prefer to use current hooks as it appears `useHistory` is outdated.

I have tried to navigate to the URL directly:

```
navigate(`/products?search=${search}`);
```

And I have tried to set the parameters as one source suggested:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('search', search);
navigate(`/products?search=${search}`);
```

I expected the `query/search` parameter to replace the search value and re-render with the new results.

Comment: Use the [useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params) hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the new [React Router V6 useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params#usesearchparams) hook:

`import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom'`

Then instantiate the hook at the top of your component:

`let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();`

Then you can manipulate the search params anywhere, in your case:

```
setSearchParams({ search: '...' );
```

Doing this along-side the `navigate()` call will basicallly lead the user to the page as the `search` param is being changed.

In your situation, I would detect if the user is already on the product list page before always running `navigate()`. You can use the `useLocation()` hook to detect what `pathname` you currently are on.

If you're on the product list page already, don't run `navigate()`. Your `useEffect` would be responsible for re-rendering the page when `search` params change using a dependency array `[searchParams.search]`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // do stuff when search params "search" variable changes
}, [searchParams.search])
```